# How to write a function that splits a colon seperated list into an array in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

I wrote the following function, but do not see why I cannot print the items to see if the function works as intended. I get a type mismatch when I try to print the item.

```
Sub Test()
    ExampleRaw = "234;BB-154;39a3"
    SemiColonListToArray (ExampleRaw)
    For Each Item In SemiColotListToArray
        Debug.Print Item
    Next Item
End Sub

Function SemiColonListToArray(semiColonList) As Variant
    SemiColonListToArray = Split(semiColonList, ";")
End Function
```

Comment: yes, I didn't assign the result to anything. I'll post the fixed code as answer. Maybe it will be deleted. It wasn't a typo, just lack of knowledge in using VBA functions

Comment: The function returns a value that you don't assign to a variable, i.e. `myArray = SemiColonListToArray(ExampleRaw)`... and then use `myArray` in the For-loop

Comment: `SemiColotListToArray` was a typo. Forcing yourself to use `Option Explicit` by enabling `Require Variable Declarations` in the VBA editor options makes debugging so much easier. That typo would have been flagged as a `variable not defined` compile error, which would have been more helpful than a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a typo in your `For Each` loop **and** you are not actually assigning anything to your `SemiColonListToArray` variable, try:

```
Sub Test()
    ExampleRaw = "234;BB-154;39a3"
    For Each Item In SemiColonListToArray(ExampleRaw)
        Debug.Print Item
    Next Item
End Sub

Function SemiColonListToArray(semiColonList) As Variant
    SemiColonListToArray = Split(semiColonList, ";")
End Function
```